# Images aren't hidden once page loads (slideDown() function in jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I used the code from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)'s website and it's supposed to have the images hidden once the page loads so that when I click on the 'button' the images are supposed to show.

My code is working except the images aren't hidden when I first load the page.

```js
 $('#click').click(function() {
   if ($("img:first").is(":hidden")) {
     $("img").slideDown("slow");
   } else {
     $("img").hide();
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="click">CLICK ME!</p>

<section id="img-container">

  <img src="04-hungry-images/food01.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food02.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food03.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food04.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food05.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food06.jpg">

</section>
```

Comment: How about `#img-container { display:none }` in the stylesheet?

Comment: Why don't you hide them using CSS???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `hide()` first:

```
$(function(){
  $("#img-container img").hide();
  $( '#click' ).click(function () {
    if ( $( "img:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
     $( "img" ).slideDown( "slow" );
    } else {
     $( "img" ).hide();
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: For the non-sense who downvoted, the OP has said that this works. `#BlindFella`

Comment: @mplungjan This **has** to be done using JavaScript, because this toggles. Else... Well, there's also a better idea...

Comment: @praveen Yes sorry! It said I had to wait like 3 minutes to accept an answer hehe probably cause you guys replied so fast! :o But thank you again!!

Comment: Welcome, @Kyla. You can do now... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You should hide image on DOM ready, or you can also hide all image from CSS on page load

**css**

```
#img-container img{ display: none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $("#img-container img").hide();
  $( '#click' ).click(function () {
    if ( $( "img:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
     $( "img" ).slideDown( "slow" );
    } else {
     $( "img" ).hide();
   }
  });

})
```

Comment: Apart from repeating my comment, why is this downvoted? Also it was suggested before Praveen's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could hide your images first, using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#img-container img").hide();
})
```

You should note that all that 'show' and 'hide' do, is to change the css display property to none or block or whatever.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Answer (score -1):

I was seeing code ,No issue in your code ,only add the little css here which is given below

```
<style>
#img-container img{ display:none;}
</style>
```

you can also see full code which is given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<style>
#img-container img{ display:none;}
</style>
<body>
<p id="click">CLICK ME!</p>

<section id="img-container">

  <img src="04-hungry-images/food01.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food02.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food03.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food04.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food05.jpg">
  <img src="04-hungry-images/food06.jpg">

</section>
</body>
<script>
 $('#click').click(function() {
   if ($("img:first").is(":hidden")) {
     $("img").slideDown("slow");
   } else {
     $("img").hide();
   }
 });

</script>
</html>
```